# Is there an optimal order of materials with differing thermal conductivity in order to decrease the heat loss to the environment?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was thinking the answer to this is a 'no', because the resistance equations for heat transfer aren't order-dependant, but I have been told that it does matter.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: For one, the thermal conductivity is temperature dependent. All else being equal, you’d want to orient the materials so they’re exposed to temperatures at which their thermal conductivity is minimized.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Seems like more of an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the equations thenselves are not order-dependent, but there are second-order effects in practice that can be significant, to wit: most insulating substances work by entraining air in such a way as to prohibit convection from getting established, which naturally makes them "fluffy". If you place a heavy insulating layer on top of a fluffy one, the fluffy layer's thickness is reduced. This decreases its insulation value and increases its heat loss rate.